# document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML="message"; is giving me an error with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here is the java script

```
window.onload="test";

  function test() {

     document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML="message";

  }
```

Here is the html page I am loading up in IE

```
<h1 class="serif">FDM Markets Trading Platform</h1>


<div class="layout" />  
 <div class="center">  
  <p class="paragraph">Login</p>
  <form name="anyForm">
   <span class="formlabel1">Username</span><input type="text" name="anyName" onKeyUp="Complete(this, event)" /></br>
   </br>
   <span class="formlabel2">Password</span><input type="text" name="password_box"></br>
   </br>
  </form>
  <span id="clock">&nbsp;</span>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="outer">

<div id="inner"></div>

</div>
```

When I load the page "message" doesnt appear in webpage and i get error that says object is null or undefined.

Comment: `test` is never even called anywhere... I guess you mean `window.onload=test;`. As for the error: No idea where that is coming from, maybe `Complete`.

Answer (score 2):

Your onload handler is wrong.  It should be this:

```
  function test() {

     document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML="message";

  }
  window.onload = test;
```

You pass a javascript function reference to `.onload`, not a string.